# Dar update apenas em campos que possuem conteúdos diferente de null - Node com Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou com uma dúvida sobre dar `update` usando o mongoose. Já tenho a rota feita e funcionando, só que eu estou com um problema.

[image: Rota update usando mongoose]

Então já desestruturei todos os dados que vou pegar do `req.body`, então quando eu passo todos os dados já preenchido para fazer `update`, vai normal, só que caso eu passei algum dado `null`, ele substitui o campo por `null`.

Após pesquisas feitas na doc do mongoose, encontrei a option `omitUndefined`, que exclui campos `undefined` do `update`, só que geralmente quando passamos ele em branco ele vem `null` e não `undefined`.

Pegando as duas imagens abaixo como exemplo, passando e não passando o campo em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Passando o `name` e `desc`, e substituindo normal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora passando a `desc` como `null`, e dentro do banco de dados substituindo o conteúdo por `null`.
E como vocês podem ver, o `price` e o `status` continuam os mesmos, pois como não passo eles no `req.body`, eles vem como `undefined`.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

**Solução encontrada**

Após recebido ajudas nas respostas do post, consegui resolver o problema com a solução abaixo usando o mongoose

```
async update(req: Request, res: Response) {
try {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { name, description, price, status, category } = req.body;

  await product.find(
    { _id: id },
    async function (err, [data]: IProductProps[]) {
      if (!err) {
        const response = await product.findByIdAndUpdate(
          { _id: id },
          {
            $set: {
              name: name || data.name,
              description: description || data.description,
              price: price || data.price,
              status: status || data.status,
              category: category || data.category,
            },
          },
          {
            new: true,
          }
        );

        return res.json(response);
      }
    }
  );
} catch {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: "error for updating a product" });
}
```

},

Comment: Ficou meio confuso! Voce nao quer salvar dados `null` no banco, e isso? Se for isso, nao seria melhor definir no modelo que tal campo nao aceita `null`? E pelo que voce escreveu, voce entende `""`(string vazia) como `null`?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, isso, não quero salvar null no mongodb, pesquisei e não tem uma propriedade por exemplo noNullable, existe uma propriedade required que torna obrigatório. Mas mesmo com essa propriedade ele aceita null nos campos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizar a função [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) antes de fazer o update dos dados.

A função find, vai te dar os valores que já estão preenchidos para o item que deseja atualizar.

Esses valores serão utilizadas como valores padrão quando os valores preenchidos pelo `req.body` não estiverem preenchidos.

### Uma versão utilizando async-await

```
exports.updateUserbyId = async (req, res) => {
    const options = { returnOriginal: false };
    const dbInstance = db.get()
    try {
        const fallbackDataObj = await dbInstance.collection('user').findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) })
        if (fallbackDataObj === null) {
            res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
            return
        }
        const result = await dbInstance.collection('user').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: {"name": req.body.name || fallbackDataObj.name }}, options)
        if (result.value === null) {
            res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
            return
        }
        res.status(200).json(result.value);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params.id}]})
    }   
}
```

### Uma versão utilizando Promises

Segue um exemplo:

```
exports.updateUserbyId = (req, res) => {
  db.get().collection('user').findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) }).then((result) => {
    if (result === null) {
        return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
    }
    const options = { returnOriginal: false };
    db.get().collection('user').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}, {$set: {"name": req.body.name || result.name }}, options).then((result1) => {
      if (result1.value === null) {
        return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
      }
      res.status(200).json(result1.value);
      }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params.id}]})
      })
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ errors: [{location: "users", msg: err, param: req.params}]})
    })
}
```

A ideia é executar a função `find` antes de executar a função `findOneAndUpdate`.

Prestar atenção em como está implementado a função `$set` pois é lá que estamos utilizando os valores consultados na função find para não gravar valores `null` no banco.

Os exemplos acima estão utilizando a lib [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Em minha implementação não estou utilizando mongoose então você terá que adaptar o código.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar adaptar ao meu código usando mongoose para ver se funciona, então basicamente a gente busca o usuário específico, e com o resultado a gente meio que se não for passado dado no req.body, ele manterá o mesmo nome de antes, faz sentido hehe. Muito obrigado

Comment: @kissinger156 tive oportunidade de melhorar o código e colocar um exemplo utilizando async-await.

Comment: Tentei fazer usando o mongoose Dani mas sem sucesso, fiz a busca com o findOne, e dentro o findByIdAndUpdate, mas ele não fez o update hehe, vou tentar de outras formas, muito obrigado

Comment: Consegui utilizar seu como base e deu certo Dani, atualizei com a solução, obrigado de verdade!